# JDBC event subscribe Oracle

Tags: oracle, events, jdbc, callback

I'd like to monitor changes in Oracle DB using JDBC connection.
Does anyone knows if it is possible to subscribe to DB events and receive events through callbacks? I do not want to poll tables for changes explicitly.

Regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with Oracle's "change notification":

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/dbmgmnt.htm#CHDEJECF

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of the Oracle database and the Oracle JDBC drivers.  Newer versions support [Database Change Notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#CACHJFCC) which allows your applications to subscribe to database events.  There is a chapter in the JDBC Developer's Guide that discusses how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you, I use 11.2.0. I think it is recent enough.